# How to manipulate multiple Folders/Dir in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qmediaplayer, qdir, qfileinfo

I want to know how to manipulate directories until I get video files.
Firstly the main Directory is `"F:/TestingVideos/"`
Inside the test video there are files e.g:1. Cash Office ,2.Rosville Gate ,3. My Videos
Each of this videos holds other folders for example Cash Office has a Directory of `"F:/TestingVideos/Cash Office/"` inside we have folders that have dates for example we have the following `"F:/TestingVideos/Cash Office/20141201/"` Inside the Date Folder I have videos that I want to play.

So far I have implemented a method:

```
void Dialog::on_loadedButton_clicked(){
  QString videoname = "F:/TestingVideos/";`
  ui->DirectoryLineEdit->setText(videoName);
  QDir dir(videoName);

QFileInfoList files = dir.entryInfoList();

QStringList MonTypeFolder = dir.entryList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs, QDir::DirsFirst);
ui->MonitoringcomboBox->addItems( MonTypeFolder);
ui->MonitoringcomboBox->show();
foreach(QFileInfo file, files){
    if(file.isDir()){
        //qDebug() << "DIR: " << file.fileName();

        // qDebug() << "Directory path file:" << file.absoluteFilePath();
        QString filePathString = file.absoluteFilePath();
        QFileInfo info = QFileInfo(filePathString);

       qDebug() << "Folders" << " are writable: " << info.isWritable() << "are readable: " << info.isReadable();

    }
    if(file.isFile()){
          qDebug() << "FILE: " << file.fileName();
    }
```

}

my output is true for my `QFileInfo info;` for writeable and readable, also I do did a `qDebug()<< info.absoluteFilePath()` I got the following results:
`"F:/TestingVideos"
 "F:/"
 "F:/TestingVideos/Cash Office"
 "F:/TestingVideos/Rosville"
 "F:/TestingVideos/My Videos"`

I want a way to manipulate the baseNames i.e. Cash Office, Rosville etc... Folders such that I can display their folders e.g. 20141201 in another combobox, since currently ui.monitoringcomboBox->show() can display the base names. I want to be able to manipulate the folders basically To a level where I where I can play a video using QUrl for example.

Comment: So if i understand right, you have a root folder  called testing videos. Inside that folder you have other folders called for example cash office etc. Inside these you have date folders and then inside these date folders you have the videos. Is that right? Is this structure always the same (3 level folder and the videos are always in the bottom folder)?

Comment: @Cits Yes that is correct and now I want to Display the Date Folders if I select for example Cash Office on my first combobox  {ui->MonitoringcomboBox->show();}, The date Folder for example 20141201 must appear on the second combobox {ui->datecombobox->show}. After that I want to be able to create like a QUrl for those videos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly you want something like this:
[image]

My code is a bit rough but you can use it as starting point:

-MainWindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include <QComboBox>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QComboBox *mainCB_;
    QComboBox *baseCB_;
    QComboBox *datesCB_;
    QComboBox *mediaCB_;

    QString path_;

    QStringList media_;

    void createComboBoxes();

private slots:
    void onBaseComboBoxActivated(QString folderText);

    void onDatesComboBoxActivated(QString folderText);

    void onMediaComboBoxActivated(QString folderText);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

-MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDir>
#include <QDebug>

#define CBWidth 140

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    media_()
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setFixedSize(840, 400);

    path_ = "/Users/its/Desktop/Testing Videos";  //insert your root folder path here
    media_ << "*.3gp" << "*.avi" << "*.m4v" << "*.mov" << "*.mp4" << "*.mpeg" << "*.mpg" << "*.3g2" << "*.mxf" << "*.swf" << "*.m2v" << "*.wmv" << "*.flv" << "*.mkv";

    QDir dir(path_);
    if(dir.exists())
    {
        createComboBoxes();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Error: Main dir " << path_ << " doesn't exist.";
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::createComboBoxes()
{
    mainCB_ = new QComboBox(this);
    mainCB_->addItem(path_.section('/', -1));
    mainCB_->setFixedWidth(CBWidth);
    mainCB_->move(50, 50);

    baseCB_ = new QComboBox(this);
    baseCB_->setFixedWidth(CBWidth);
    baseCB_->move(250, 50);

    datesCB_ = new QComboBox(this);
    datesCB_->setFixedWidth(CBWidth);
    datesCB_->move(450, 50);

    mediaCB_ = new QComboBox(this);
    mediaCB_->setFixedWidth(CBWidth);
    mediaCB_->move(650, 50);

    QDir mainFolderDir(path_);
    QStringList mainFolderContent = mainFolderDir.entryList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs, QDir::DirsFirst);
    baseCB_->addItems(mainFolderContent);
    connect(baseCB_, SIGNAL(activated(QString)), this, SLOT(onBaseComboBoxActivated(QString)));
    onBaseComboBoxActivated(baseCB_->itemText(0));
    connect(datesCB_, SIGNAL(activated(QString)), this, SLOT(onDatesComboBoxActivated(QString)));
    connect(mediaCB_, SIGNAL(activated(QString)), this, SLOT(onMediaComboBoxActivated(QString)));
}

void MainWindow::onBaseComboBoxActivated(QString folderText)
{
    QDir baseFolderDir(path_ + "/" + folderText);
    if(baseFolderDir.exists())
    {
        QStringList baseFolderContent = baseFolderDir.entryList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs, QDir::DirsFirst);
        datesCB_->clear();
        datesCB_->addItems(baseFolderContent);
        onDatesComboBoxActivated(datesCB_->itemText(0));
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Error: Base dir " << path_ + "/" + folderText << " doesn't exist.";
    }
}

void MainWindow::onDatesComboBoxActivated(QString datesText)
{
    QDir datesFolderDir(path_ + "/" + baseCB_->currentText() + "/" + datesText);
    if(datesFolderDir.exists())
    {
        QStringList datesFolderContent = datesFolderDir.entryList(media_, QDir::Files, QDir::Name);
        mediaCB_->clear();
        mediaCB_->addItems(datesFolderContent);
        onMediaComboBoxActivated(mediaCB_->itemText(0));
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Error: Dates dir " << path_ + "/" + baseCB_->currentText() + "/" + datesText << " doesn't exist.";
    }
}

void MainWindow::onMediaComboBoxActivated(QString mediaText)
{
    qDebug() << "Media selected with URL:" << path_ + "/" + baseCB_->currentText() + "/" + datesCB_->currentText() + "/" + mediaText;
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: @ CItis. Thank you very much, that is what I am looking for WOW, If my reputation was Higher I was going to rate you up. If I may ask, how can I Upgrade my skills to be as good as you are?

Comment: @Citis, thank you again For your assistant, this is a good starting point that you have gave me. It works perfectly and does what is required.

Comment: @BillalMabuza Im glad that it helped you. Well the only secret to get better is to practice a lot. If you are a beginner you should check some learning qt videos in youtube (there are some good channels) or learning pages. Check this thread too: stackoverflow.com/questions/5510811/qt-learning-resources Oh and even if you don't have enough rep to upvote you still can mark my answer as valid clicking the ✓ button.